# How do I set up Redshift Interpreter in Apache Zeppelin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, apache-zeppelin

I have installed Apache Zepellin on my AWS EC2 to visualize the data in Redshift. I can connect to Redshift from EC2 via odbc using pyodbc. I can reach the Zeppelin notebook from the browser. I tried setting up the Redshift interpreter but it seems to be failing. Please find the attached interpreter screen shot. Also find the error attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, it seems that you are using postgres interpreter instead of JDBC, what version are you using? You can check by click `anonymous` -> `about zeppelin`.

Comment: Hello 1amda, if I am not grossly mistaken then postgres should have worked with Redshift. The version of zeppelin is 0.7.1

Comment: I didn't use postgres interpreter so not sure about that. But [0.7.1 doc for Zeppelin](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.1/interpreter/jdbc.html#redshift) has `redshift` section not in postgres doc.

Comment: Hello. Kunal. 
You should set the `default` properties not `postgres` like https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.1/interpreter/jdbc.html#redshift

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, actually I created new interpreter with jdbc and it worked.